# Scraping Asxp page with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I83wy.png)I am trying to scrape this page using Beautiful Soup, I 1st tried to find any API/Json behind the page which I couldn't find. And then I was trying a BS and HTML parser, but I can't get anywhere with it.
I am not able to do so coz the page is calling a function with onclick GetFiiStatistics('F-INDEX FUTURES').

How can I go about scraping pages like these?

webpage:
https://www.motilaloswal.com/markets/derivative-market/FII-Statistics.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded via Javascript from their API. Unfortunately, I don't know, how `INPUT`, `CATAGORY` and `FLAG` values are computed:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = 'https://www.motilaloswal.com/ControllerBeta/APIRequest.aspx'

data = {
  'INPUT':'3yDBtksOiDjLLYaySd5NYgCcFnUOx8Jh2c8SRJvEhAs=',
  'CATAGORY':'Q668CVoAKYOr7whA+PW25A==',
  'FLAG':'VrTQQDRa72uSLVOyZO5Nqg=='
}

json_data = json.loads(requests.post(api_url, data=data).json())

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                IndexType                 Date  BuyContracts  BuyValue  SellContracts  SellValue  Net_BuySellValue  OIContracts_eod  OIValue_eod
0    INDEX FUTURES         2020-07-14T00:00:00         67037  4403.320          88350   6048.750         -1645.430           123985      8799.15
1    INDEX FUTURES         2020-07-13T00:00:00         53612  3644.000          61174   4142.300          -498.300           105126      7803.56
2    INDEX FUTURES         2020-07-10T00:00:00         62735  4313.250          83916   5923.270         -1610.020           113346      8369.47
3    INDEX FUTURES         2020-07-09T00:00:00         67222  4773.340          51094   3442.520          1330.820           119977      8971.28
4    INDEX FUTURES         2020-07-08T00:00:00         83367  5661.640          69042   4659.280          1002.360           106027      7686.32
..                    ...                  ...           ...       ...            ...        ...               ...              ...          ...
495  INDEX FUTURES         2018-07-05T00:00:00         28566  2585.923          21393   1881.601           704.322           243417     19847.72
496  INDEX FUTURES         2018-07-04T00:00:00         21339  1875.184          26507   2425.003          -549.819           245786     20201.28
497  INDEX FUTURES         2018-07-03T00:00:00         30019  2610.728          28837   2563.647            47.081           237564     19322.63
498  INDEX FUTURES         2018-07-02T00:00:00         24976  2191.751          29501   2541.589          -349.838           226100     18203.48
499  INDEX FUTURES         2018-06-29T00:00:00         45399  3814.480          27297   2371.817          1442.663           227041     18387.33

[500 rows x 9 columns]
```

---

EDIT: To scrape other tabs, change the `data=` parameter in request:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = 'https://www.motilaloswal.com/ControllerBeta/APIRequest.aspx'

data_future = {
  'INPUT':'3yDBtksOiDjLLYaySd5NYgCcFnUOx8Jh2c8SRJvEhAs=',
  'CATAGORY':'Q668CVoAKYOr7whA+PW25A==',
  'FLAG':'VrTQQDRa72uSLVOyZO5Nqg=='
}

data_option = {
    'INPUT': '3yDBtksOiDjLLYaySd5NYmcoKC8x7z5PFO880mjcQ2U=',
    'CATAGORY': 'Q668CVoAKYOr7whA+PW25A==',
    'FLAG': "VrTQQDRa72uSLVOyZO5Nqg=="
}

data_stock_future = {
    'INPUT': '7F5jZM46TTOICwT1N6AfqkP7gWI2CpTGCWmll4bhYow=',
    'CATAGORY': 'Q668CVoAKYOr7whA+PW25A==',
    'FLAG': 'VrTQQDRa72uSLVOyZO5Nqg=='
}

data_stock_option = {
    'INPUT': '7F5jZM46TTOICwT1N6Afqv1N6pCh+1OrTfhSwG6Azes=',
    'CATAGORY': 'Q668CVoAKYOr7whA+PW25A==',
    'FLAG': 'VrTQQDRa72uSLVOyZO5Nqg=='
}


json_data = json.loads(requests.post(api_url, data=data_stock_option).json())  # <-- change data= to data_stock_future or data_option ...

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                IndexType                 Date  BuyContracts  BuyValue  SellContracts  SellValue  Net_BuySellValue  OIContracts_eod  OIValue_eod
0    STOCK OPTIONS         2020-07-14T00:00:00         52546  4349.020          54139   4525.850          -176.830           115998     7661.010
1    STOCK OPTIONS         2020-07-13T00:00:00         50604  4242.330          52221   4413.040          -170.710           110663     7329.990
2    STOCK OPTIONS         2020-07-10T00:00:00         82502  6218.200          82608   6219.420            -1.220           109680     7232.900
3    STOCK OPTIONS         2020-07-09T00:00:00         64743  4725.430          64613   4714.460            10.970           104780     6945.740
4    STOCK OPTIONS         2020-07-08T00:00:00         75481  5201.770          75713   5220.580           -18.810           100200     6584.390
..                    ...                  ...           ...       ...            ...        ...               ...              ...          ...
495  STOCK OPTIONS         2018-07-05T00:00:00         94696  6728.086          93256   6617.059           111.027            66773     4471.483
496  STOCK OPTIONS         2018-07-04T00:00:00         68719  4762.333          69376   4794.350           -32.017            59195     4005.045
497  STOCK OPTIONS         2018-07-03T00:00:00         64283  4351.226          64982   4347.153             4.073            53028     3581.946
498  STOCK OPTIONS         2018-07-02T00:00:00         74479  4913.606          74730   4897.239            16.367            44627     3024.131
499  STOCK OPTIONS         2018-06-29T00:00:00         69730  4694.675          68447   4645.350            49.325            35486     2421.744

[500 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for this!
This is the data for Index futures there are 3 more tabs on the page. any idea how can i get input category and flag for all those data?
Can you share how you got this tags and category?

Comment: @yashaswikashyap I updated my question. When you open Firefox developer tools (or in Chrome) -> Network tab and click on the table tab, you will see parameters that are sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
This was a nightmare for me